# How can we write to Azure Synapse dedicated SQL pool tables from synapse with Service Principal authentication?

Tags: pyspark, azure-synapse

We are pushing data to Synapse dedicated sql pool ( formerly Azure SQL DW) from Databricks / PySpark using jdbc connector and it is very slow.

Can someone please help with code snippet to load data using some SQL DW conenctor using Service Principal authentication which gives better performance

Scala code snippet to push the data would also work if some desired library could be found that gives better performance

P.S. We don't have Storage account key authentication as an approved method for data lake storage so could not follow what is mentioned on the azure databricks pages.

Comment: Regarding performance maybe you can use the Azure Blob Storage connector for PolyBase in combination with the PySpark's write function. This method will provide better performance compared to using JDBC connectors.

Comment: Could you please point me to some link/blog that outlines some of the snippets?

Answer (score 0):

To load data using some SQL DW conenctor using Service Principal authentication. Thanks to @[Daniel Moody](https://www.thedataswamp.com/?author=604e09d019133203f7809090)
This [Blog](https://www.thedataswamp.com/blog/databricks-connect-to-azure-sql-with-service-principal) and this [source](https://github.com/microsoft/sql-spark-connector) should help you
You can follow these steps to connect Dedicated SQL pool with the SPN.
To load data using some SQL DW conenctor using Service Principal authentication

. Create a App regestration Application ID generate a secret

. Install required drivers on Databricks cluster.
**com.microsoft.azure:spark-mssql-connector:1.0.2** **Maven** Library

**adal** 1.2.7 Pypi please refer this [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/adal/)

[image]

. In the Key vault genrate the secrets for the CLIENT ID & CLIENT SECRET.

[image]
In the databricks end you to create a secret scope.
You can use the  https://#secrets/createScope. to create a scope.
This will be the UI for creating a Scope.
[image]

In the Key Vault you will get the Vaues for the DNS and the Resource ID.
[image]
Now in the databricks you can use the below code.
This Below code will help you connect to your database

```
import adal

resource_app_id_url = "https://database.windows.net/"

service_principal_id = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "defaultSc1", key = "DatabricksID")
service_principal_secret = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "defaultSc1", key = "DatabricksID")
tenant_id = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "defaultSc1", key = "TenantId")
authority = "https://login.windows.net/" + tenant_id


azure_sql_url = "jdbc:sqlserver://example.database.windows.net"
database_name = "dev"
db_table = "dbo.Users"
```

Next

```
context = adal.AuthenticationContext(authority)

token = context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(resource_app_id_url, service_principal_id, service_principal_secret)

access_token = token["accessToken"]

emperorDf = spark.read \

.format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \

.option("url", azure_sql_url) \

.option("dbtable", db_table) \

.option("databaseName", database_name) \

.option("accessToken", access_token) \

.option("encrypt", "true") \

.option("hostNameInCertificate", "*.database.windows.net") \

.load()

display(UsersDf)
```

These steps should help you with the Connect to you SQL DWH with SPN.